# Unable to find linux kernel source code after downloading

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I downloaded linux source code using:

```
 sudo apt-get build-dep --no-install-recommends linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

But, on trying to find ext4 fs files under /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-72/fs/ext4:
I only find Kconfig and Makefile files. How do I get the actual source code?

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux

Comment: Your command is wrong: it is to download the build dependencies, not the sources. In addition, you are looking where the headers are installed (created by the package you are requiring the dependencies, but such packages have huge number of header file (depending on the kernel options/architecture). In addition, you are not telling us which distribution you are looking. Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-and-modify-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get (and so you are also off-topix. our sister sites may be more relevant)

Answer (score 0):

or [kernel.org](https://kernel.org)

But if you need the sources of the kernel that is used in your distribution - make sure you install a ***src*** package first,  then find where are the sources installed by your package manager